# Solving multiple pathfinding problems efficiently

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, planning

Let $V$ be a set of nodes, $c : V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ be an edge cost function, and $h : V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an [admissible heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic). Suppose we want to solve *multiple* independent [least-cost path problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem): from $a_1$ to $b_1$, from $a_2$ to $b_2$, and so on.

One approach is to run an all-pairs algorithm like the $\Theta(|V|^3)$ [Floyd–Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) or $O(|V|^2 \log |V| + |V| |E|)$ [Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm), and then apply the results to each problem.

Another approach is to run separate algorithms like [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) on each individual problem.

My question is: Can we do better than these? For example, is there a way we can *reuse* A* computations from prior problems to speed up the next problem? Perhaps we can exploit the [Bellman optimality property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation) of the recovered paths, or take advantage of other values that were computed by the preceding A* algorithm runs?